# Recursive calculation on CTE

Tags: sql-server-2012, recursive-query, reportbuilder3.0

I'm looking for a way, how to calculate formula as below:

```
month 1
result_1 = result_0 + (number_of_open - number_of_close), where result_0 = 0
month 2
result_2 = result_1 + (number_of_open - number_of_close)
month 3
result_3 = result_2 + (number_of_open - number_of_close)
```

I know how to calculate it when results are shown from the very beginning, means:

[image]

but when I have some dates chosen, for example from February 1, 2015, it doesn't count correctly:

[image]

It seems to be counted from the taken moment.
Is there any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Seeing how you did rolling count would be helpful to see the scope of conditions and how data is partitioned. Also this question seems to be about the query and not about building a report in report builder 3.0.

Comment: Information about building a report was additional to give a wider range of what I need. However yes - this is correct it's more about the query. Sorry if it was confusing. I think after few tries I am one step closer to the aim, I found a way how to calculate it with possibility to change a range of dates without changing values of each month. It was quite simple, in short: 'select sum(o.number_of_activities - c.number_of_activities) over (ORDER BY c.full_year, c.month_number) as [backlog]' inside the temp tables. Now I need to find how to add it to the rest of the code. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is very important your ORDER BY is correct in calculating aggregated rolling number as you described. Could not point out the problem without the query. More about OVER(); https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found a good enough workaround for this. I've been searching how to solve this, and found that I can use [SUM() OVER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) and it will work as a Running Total. But if I need it to work inside given time-range, I had to use subquery, so I was not able to make it with CTE and had to use temp tables. My code is now:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
   drop table #Temp1
end

SELECT * into #Temp1
   from (
SELECT
 datepart(yy, t3.[datestamp]) AS full_year 
,datepart(mm, t3.[datestamp]) AS month_number
,count(*) as number_of_activities
,t2.affected_item
FROM [sm70prod].[dbo].[ACTSVCMGTM1] AS t3 
JOIN [sm70prod].[dbo].[INCIDENTSM1] AS t2 ON t3.number = t2.incident_id
WHERE
t2.affected_item like 'Service_name'
AND (t3.[type] LIKE 'Open')
GROUP BY t2.affected_item, datepart(yy, t3.[datestamp]), datepart(mm, t3.[datestamp])
)
as databases (full_year, month_number, number_of_activities, affected_item)

;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp2') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
       drop table #Temp2
end

SELECT * into #Temp2
   from (
SELECT
 datepart(yy, t3.[datestamp]) AS full_year 
,datepart(mm, t3.[datestamp]) AS month_number
,count(*) as number_of_activities
,t2.affected_item
FROM [sm70prod].[dbo].[ACTSVCMGTM1] AS t3 
JOIN [sm70prod].[dbo].[INCIDENTSM1] AS t2 ON t3.number = t2.incident_id
WHERE
t2.affected_item like 'Service_name'
AND (t3.[type] LIKE 'Closed')
GROUP BY t2.affected_item, datepart(yy, t3.[datestamp]), datepart(mm, t3.[datestamp])
)
as databases (full_year, month_number, number_of_activities, affected_item)


select * from (select sum(o.number_of_activities - c.number_of_activities) over (ORDER BY c.full_year, c.month_number) as [backlog]
from #Temp1 o full join #Temp2 c on o.full_year = c.full_year and o.month_number = c.month_number) sub
--where 'time condition'
```

and I can put my dates/time condition in 'where' clause.

Now the issue is how to correctly add it to the code where I use CTE and few 'selects' combined with 'union all's. But this is a story for another question, I guess.